# Using OVA file (VirtualBox image) to create Google Compute Engine VM instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, hortonworks-sandbox

I want to load the Hortonworks sandbox [VirtualBox/VMware image](http://hortonassets.s3.amazonaws.com/2.4/HDP_2.4_virtualbox_v3.ova) in Google Compute Engine. Is it possible? If yes, how?

I am able to load the image locally in the laptop, but that eats up all the resources and slows down everything.

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach to trying out HDP on Google Compute Engine would be to use [`bdutil`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/blob/master/platforms/hdp/README.md) to deploy a Hadoop cluster which you can configure to install any subset of HDP components, rather than converting a VM image from one format to another.

There are two possible approaches:

1. Using `bdutil`, modify [`ambari_env.sh`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/blob/master/platforms/hdp/ambari_env.sh) and add `ZEPPELIN` to the list of services in `AMBARI_SERVICES` variable to get it installed at the same time as other services.
2. Alternatively, use Ambari UI after your cluster is deployed to add the Zeppelin service.

Comment: thanks for the pointer to bdutil, I tried that, but that doesn't give Zeppelin along with distribution. while sandbox has Zeppelin, and the tutorials are based on that

Comment: Zeppelin is available in [HDP 2.4](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/apache-zeppelin-hdp-2-4/). You should be able to modify [`ambari_env.sh`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/blob/master/platforms/hdp/ambari_env.sh) and add `ZEPPELIN` to the list of services in `AMBARI_SERVICES` variable to get it installed. If that doesn't work, please file an issue on the GitHub project.

Comment: You should also be able to use the Ambari UI after your cluster is deployed to add/remove components and services such as Zeppelin. Please let me know if either of these approaches worked for you and resolve the question if so.